# Emacs Execution of Python script with C-c C-c goes Unrecognized

Tags: emacs24, python-mode

**Setup:** Emacs 24.2.1 running on Ubuntu 13.04
Using version provided by the software center ("modified by Debian").

**Issue:**
The binding "C-c C-c" is not recognized with python.el (it does work on python-mode.el) even though C-h b lists it as a valid combination associated with "python-send-buffer".

The troubleshooting section in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProgrammingWithPythonDotEl
suggests it has to do with the point needing to be at the "very bottom" but the solution provided seems to be for C-c C-r and I don't know if it applies to C-c as well.

Also similar to:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2007-09/msg01665.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the python.el shipped now is different from 24.2, seems to cure on Ubuntu's side only:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Also consider installing latest release.

[http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)